# NoSuchElementException while trying to get information from Scanner

Tags: java, file, jfilechooser, nosuchelementexception

I'm a newbie and I'm only trying to open a file using `JFileChooser` then analyze it using Scanner. The `File` I need to open is a .txt file filled with information separated with a tab (`'\t'`). I don't know why I have a `NoSuchElementException` as the `println` does show the filename. I've put a sample here that does the problem. Thanks for your support and help! Any explanation is welcomed.

```
    JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser();

    int returnValue = choice.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

        File file = choice.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println("You chose : " + file.getName());

        try{

            Scanner readedFile = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\t");
            //I tried \t and \\t
            System.out.print(readedFile.next()); //Crash Here, crash with .nextLine too

        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }          
    }
```

THANKS!!!!!

EDIT : 
Thanks MIW for the fast answer. It seems like the teacher gave us a bad file. I create a file myself and it works.

Comment: Can you please lemme know whats the print in "You chose :"

Comment: Its full file path name or file name only

Comment: Filename only sir, for the path it's file.getAbsolutePath();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you get a "NoSuchFileException"? That's from the nio package which is not really relevant here.

When I run your code, it either prints a "NoSuchElementException" (when using a file without any \t in it) or it prints the first token and exits.

I think you should check the file that you choose and see whether it actually contains the content that you want it to.

I think your code should use \t (not \t)

Comment: and with \\t or \t it does the same

Comment: That means the scanner finds the file and reads it, but the content is not what the scanner expects.